# Consulta substitui id da tabela principal

Tags: laravel

Estou tentando realizar uma consulta na tabela "despesas" que possui chave estrangeira.
[image: banco]

Ao realizar a consulta. A coluna "id" da tabela "despesas" é substituída pela "id" de "despesa_categorias"

Estou realizando a consulta da seguinte forma:

```
$despesas= Despesa::query()
        ->where('id_user', '=', "$usuario->id")
        ->join('despesa_categorias', 'despesas.id_des_cat', '=', 'despesa_categorias.id')
        ->whereYear('data_referencia', '=', "$ano")
        ->whereMonth('data_referencia', '=', "$mes")
        ->get();
```

O meu retorno é:

```
{"id":3,"id_user":1,"id_des_cat":3,"valor":42.9,"descricao":"teste","data_referencia":"2020-07-15","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"categoria":"energia"}
```

Onde "id" está vindo da tabela "despesa_categorias". Como posso manter o "id" da tabela "despesas" ao realizar a consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema. Mesmo sendo meio obvio, ainda é algo que me fez passar um bom tempo tentando entender.Então vou deixar registrado

Como as duas tabela tinham a coluna com o mesmo nome a coluna "id" acabava sendo substituída, para resolver fiz da seguinte forma.

```
$despesas= Despesa::query()
        ->where('id_user', '=', "$usuario->id")
        ->join('despesa_categorias', 'despesas.id_des_cat', '=', 'despesa_categorias.id')
        ->select('despesas.*', 'despesa_categorias.categoria')
        ->whereYear('data_referencia', '=', "$ano")
        ->whereMonth('data_referencia', '=', "$mes")
        ->get();
```

Usando o select consegui selecionar todas as colunas da tabela principal, incluindo o id e trazer a penas a coluna "categoria" da tabela "despesa_categorias".